# SQL WHERE IN equivalent but with AND instead of OR

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I came across a post that said

```
whereas IN ('val1', 'val2', 'val3') is basically equivalent to

WHERE
(
   column = 'val1'
   OR
   column = 'val2'
   OR 
   column = 'val3'
)
```

My question is, is there something that replaces the ORs with ANDs such as:

```
WHERE
(
   column = 'val1'
   AND
   column = 'val2'
   AND 
   column = 'val3'
)
```

Comment: A field/column can't have more than 1 value at the same time.

Comment: I was trying to do a group by where a column must contain those values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not exactly.  This problem can often be solved using aggregation:

```
select id  -- of some sort
from t
where column in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
group by id
having count(*) = 3;  -- all values accounted for
```

This assumes that `column` does not have duplicated values for a given id.  If that is possible, use `having count(distinct column) = 3`.

Comment: having count(distinct column) = 3;

Comment: When you have a tag table, this becomes important, unfortunately when your dataset is massive, where you have a 0(n * x) one to many relationships.. where x is tag values, n is some subject/domain, these types of matches are better done with products like elastic search.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, no.  Because a single row column can't have 3 different values in it at once.

I suspect you want to return only records that have only rows with those 3 specific values, but that's just a guess.  Gordon's answer is a good solution if that's the case.